# Face landmark detection using Intel RealSense Compatiblity SDK

Tags: opencv, realsense

I am using the latest Intel Realsense SDK see https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense

All the other SDKs seem to be discontinued.

I have access to the rgb and depth stream and I have aligned the depth stream to the rgb stream. I have face detection on the rgb stream and would now like to get face landmark info within the face. What are my options here? I want the face landmark to happen using the depth stream. Is there an SDK I can use for this?